# Primer elemento de un array es undefined utilizando el objeto set y el método map juntos

Tags: javascript, json, web

Tengo un archivo Json y al querer generar un nuevo `array` utilizando `set` y `map` me genera un primer elemento `undefined`, básicamente lo que busco con el código es que se guarde algunos valores del objeto en un `array` ,especificamente los valores de la propiedad `datos.indicador` que cumplan con la condición que en la propiedad `datos.dimension === 'Empleo'` para luego utilizarlo en un select, cabe destacar que al renderizar el html, el primer elemento del select justamente muestra "undefined", intente depurarlo desde el navegador pero tampoco pude dar con el problema, a continuación dejo el fragmento del código junto con algo del código Json(el archivo es muy extenso para colocarlo todo).

```js
const datos = [
    {
        "bloque":"Condiciones materiales",
        "dimension":"Vivienda",
        "indicador":"Calidad de los materiales - piso",
        "encabezado":["Suficiente","Parcial","Insuficiente"],
        "col":["pisosufi","pisopar","pisoinsu"]
    },
        {
        "bloque":"Condiciones materiales",
        "dimension":"Ingreso",
        "indicador":"Mediana IPCF",
        "encabezado":["Total","Mujeres","Varones"],
        "col":["medianaipcfto","medianaipcfmu","medianaipcfva"]
    },
    {
        "bloque":"Condiciones materiales",
        "dimension":"Empleo",
        "indicador":"Porcentaje de poblacion NI",
        "encabezado":["Total","Mujeres","Varones"],
        "col":["nito","nimu","niva"]
    },
    {
        "bloque":"Condiciones materiales",
        "dimension":"Empleo",
        "indicador":"Brecha por sexo - Jovenes NI ",
        "encabezado":["Brecha por sexo - Jovenes NI "],
        "col":["sexni"]
    }
    
]
    

      const indicadores = [...new Set(datos.map(function(dato){
        if(dato.dimension === 'Empleo'){
          return dato.indicador;
        }
      }))];

console.log({indicadores});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes del `map()` puedes hacer un `filter()` y mapear lo que encuentra, en este caso, a las claves `dimension` que sus valores digan `Empleo`, por ejemplo:

```js
const datos = [
    {
        "bloque":"Condiciones materiales",
        "dimension":"Vivienda",
        "indicador":"Calidad de los materiales - piso",
        "encabezado":["Suficiente","Parcial","Insuficiente"],
        "col":["pisosufi","pisopar","pisoinsu"]
    },
        {
        "bloque":"Condiciones materiales",
        "dimension":"Ingreso",
        "indicador":"Mediana IPCF",
        "encabezado":["Total","Mujeres","Varones"],
        "col":["medianaipcfto","medianaipcfmu","medianaipcfva"]
    },
    {
        "bloque":"Condiciones materiales",
        "dimension":"Empleo",
        "indicador":"Porcentaje de poblacion NI",
        "encabezado":["Total","Mujeres","Varones"],
        "col":["nito","nimu","niva"]
    },
    {
        "bloque":"Condiciones materiales",
        "dimension":"Empleo",
        "indicador":"Brecha por sexo - Jovenes NI ",
        "encabezado":["Brecha por sexo - Jovenes NI "],
        "col":["sexni"]
    }
    
]

const indicadores = [...new Set(datos
  .filter(dato => dato.dimension === 'Empleo')
  .map(dato => dato.indicador))];

console.log({indicadores});
```

Comment: La respuesta que me diste efectivamente es solución al error pero me gustaría si puedes explicarme brevemente por que en mi código el primer elemento da por resultado ```undefined```, muchas gracias. @Cris223511.dev

Comment: Sucede que en el caso de que no se cumpla la condición de que si `dato.dimension` es igual a `Empleo`, no habrá que mapear y el `map` te devuelve `undefined`, es por eso que mejor hay que hacer antes un `filter` y mapear con lo que se filtró, osea, mapear los `Empleo` que devolvió el `filter`, así nunca retorna `undefined`